# ASP.NET Core injecting DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Me sale este error en el "catch" al inyectar datos:

> Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
>   Object name: 'AsyncDisposer'.

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{


    public HomeController(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        CreateRoles(serviceProvider);

    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult About()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }


    private async Task CreateRoles(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {

        string msg=string.Empty;

        try
        {

            var rolesManger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();

            var userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();


            String[] rolesName = { "Admin", "User", "SuperAdmin" };

            foreach (var item in rolesName)
            {
                var existeRoles = await rolesManger.RoleExistsAsync(item);

                if (!existeRoles) 
                {
                    await rolesManger.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(item));
                }

            }


           var usr = await userManager.FindByIdAsync("705f393e-d494-4bef-8b59-e542a44c53f3");
            await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(usr, "Admin");


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            msg = ex.Message;

        }


    }

    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
}
```

}

Startup.cs:

```
 public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        //services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
          //  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser,IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

He buscado en google pero ninguna solución me sirve, por favor échame un mano para solucionarlo, mil gracias

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el método `CreateRoles` es asíncrono y lo estás invocando en el constructor el cual no puede ser asíncrono.

El flujo de la ejecución no va a "esperar" a que se termine de ejecutar el método y pasará a ejecutar la acción del controlador, una vez que la acción termina el framework desecha los recursos que cuyo ciclo de vida corresponde a solo la duración del *request* tal como `UserManager`.  Es posible que en este punto, el método `CreateRoles` continue con su ejecución, teniendo referencia a objetos que han sido desechados (*disposed*).

Viendo el código asumo que quieres asegurar que existan roles antes que se ejecute el resto del programa.  Lo que te recomiendo es que saques esa inicialización del constructor del controlador, el constructor no es un buen lugar para ponerlo.  Podrías ponerlo en un *Middleware* antes de la ejecución del flujo regular de MVC.

Así creas un middleware:

```
public class MyMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _next = next;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        // tu código

        await _next(httpContext);
    }
}

public static class MiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

y lo registras en el `Startup`:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseMyMiddleware();
app.UseMvc(routes => //...
```

el orden es importante aquí, asegúrate de que sea registrado luego de la autenticación y antes de MVC.